# Create File in /var/app/current directory after successful deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create a file in the `/var/app/current` directory **after** a successful deployment. I already created a configuration file under `.ebextensions` but the file is not being created. I think it is always overwritten because the files are firstly checked out at `/tmp/deployment/application`. I don't want to track the file in my VCS.

My config file:

```
# .ebextensions/create_file.config
files:
  "/var/app/current/src/webapp/dist/testfile.html":
  mode: "000644"
  owner: nodejs
  group: nodejs
  content: |
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
    <body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if your full folder does not exist, you try to create it: `commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /var/app/current/src/webapp/dist/"
    ignoreErrors: true`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though it's not explicitly stated in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html), all `.ebextensions` commands are run **prior** to the final deployment step. That is, they are all executed while the new version of your application is being deployed to `/var/app/ondeck` but before that directory is renamed to `/var/app/current`.

So what's happening is that your `testfile.html` is being written to the **old** directory `/var/app/current`, which is later deleted and replaced with the new directory `/var/app/ondeck`.

There is no officially-supported mechanism for executing commands **after** the directory is moved, but I (and many other people) use [an unofficial workaround](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137136). Basically, write a shell script that moves or creates the file you need and drop it into `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/`.

Comment: Thank you Brian, next to the workaround there are some other valuable informations in the provided thread.